If an absolutely cont. random variable is conditionally discrete given another, is their joint distribution concentrated on a set of measure zero?
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous random variables, and $Y$ is conditionally discrete given $X$ in the sense that, for almost all $x$, there is a finite or countably infinite set $S_x$ such that $\Pr(Y \in S_x|X=x) = 1$. Is the joint distribution of $X,Y$ concentrated on a two-dimensional set of measure zero? If so, how to show this? If not, what is a counterexample?
